# How to disable setting value of getter object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a getter function called data, it's a object, which i'm only able to get value since no setter had been set.

However i'm able to set value within the data object, how can i disable this?

**dataClass.ts**

```
interface dataInterface {
  test1: string;
  data: object;
}

class dataModel {
  private _data: dataInterface;
  get data(): dataInterface {
    return this._data;
  }
}
```

**externalClass.ts**

```
class externalClass {
  testData = new dataModel()

  testing(){
    this.testData.data.test1 = "WW"; // i'm able to set value which i shouldn't (data is a getter)
    this.testData.data = {test1:"WW",data:{} // this will trow error as expected
  }
}
```

Please refer to the code above, and advice how to deny setting value of getter object

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you can set the value of the returned object even if the getter is read-only. You are not changing the reference stored in `data` you are changing the value of one of the object fields which is allowed.

You can use the `Readonly` mapped type to mark that all fields of the returned object are readonly:

```
interface dataInterface {
  test1: string;
  data: object;
}

class dataModel {
  private _data: dataInterface;
  get data(): Readonly<dataInterface> {
    return this._data;
  }
}

class externalClass {
  testData = new dataModel()

  testing(){
    this.testData.data.test1 = "WW"; // error
  }
}
```

**Note** if you have a more nested structure, `Readonly` will only mark the first level as readonly, you might want to create a `DeepReadonly` type as suggested [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13923)